# Update Multiple Records with Unique Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm looking for a way to programmatically update multiple records in attribute tables.  The information to be updated for each record is unique.

History of Problem: Datafile names were truncated at the time of shapefile creation.  The attribute tables for the features have been exported to a spreadsheet and the full datafile names have been identified.  Basically, I have a spreadsheet with OBJECT IDs and the corrected full datafile name that needs to overwrite what is currently in the attribute table for the record.

It makes sense to me that it would be some sort of loop, but I'm not a savvy programmer and the fact that the replacement text is unique for most of the records makes it harder for me to wrap my head around.

I'm using ArcMap.

Comment: I'm guessing this is GIS Software? What software are you using?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  I'm using ArcMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use field calculator with [ArcMap](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Making%20field%20calculations).

First you can do a join on the object ID's then do the field calculation on the old field and set the value to the full datafile field.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution.  I use joins and filed calculator all of the time and it didn't even cross my mind as something that could be used to solve this problem.  I think this will get the job done.